# Django App Failing while pushing to Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: python, django, cloud-foundry, pcf

Brand new to Python and Django .

Created first ever app in here.

My Django Rest API is working good in local. I tried deploying to PCF.

my manage.py looks like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and requirement.txt is

```
Django
django-toolbelt
djangorestframework
gunicorn
```

and runtime.txt is

```
python-x.x.x
```

I created Manifest.yml too like

```
applications:
- name: MyPythonApp
  memory: 128MB
  disk_quota: 256MB
  random-route: true
```

However i am getting error like below

```
 File "manage.py", line 16
   2019-12-26T13:12:06.88-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     ) from exc
   2019-12-26T13:12:06.88-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR          ^
   2019-12-26T13:12:06.88-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you literally have the runtime.txt set to `x.x.x`? You should probably be setting 2.7.x or 3.y.x, where why is the minor version of Python you run and test with locally. Otherwise things might end up being different in your local testing vs when you deploy to Cloud Foundry. Also, if that doesn't help. Please include the full output of running `cf push`.

Comment: i edited my cf push with
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

and now i am getting 

2019-12-26T13:37:52.46-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
   2019-12-26T13:37:52.47-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
   2019-12-26T13:37:52.47-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Current thread 0x00007f03a268f740 (most recent call first):

Comment: OK, need to see what is happening when you `cf push`. What is the full output of running that command?